# Integral proof that $\ln(xy)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)$

Tags: integration, logarithms

It's probably a very question with a very easy answer for all of you.
Apparently, one can define the natural logarithm ln(xy) as the definite integral t^(-1) from 1 to xy.
If you split it into two integrals, one going from 1 to x and the other one going from x to xy you can present this natural logarithm as the sum of the two integrals. This makes all sense.
According to my lecture slides our professor replaced the integral from x to xy by the integral from 1 to y. Finally, we get the sum of the integral from 1 to x and from 1 to y. Which can be written as ln(x) + ln(y).
It seems to me that he just eliminated x from the interval. This is why we ended up with the new interval 1 to y instead of x to xy. I've never seen this before. Is this a valid integration rule I should know or was the reason behind his procedure a different one?

Looking forward to your answers

Comment: If you make the substitution $u=t/x$ you see that $\int_x^{xy}\frac{1}{t}dt=\int_1^y\frac{1}{u}du=\ln y$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. To get better results, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions, otherwise, some users won't even read them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its just the rule of substitution.
$\displaystyle\int_{t=1}^{t=xy}t^{-1}dt = \displaystyle\int_{t=1}^{t=x}t^{-1}dt  + \displaystyle\int_{t=x}^{t=xy}t^{-1}dt  $

Consider $\displaystyle\int_{t=x}^{t=xy}t^{-1}dt $

Substitute $t = xm$.  Then, $\dfrac{dt}{dm} = x $

As $t$ goes from $x$ to $xy$, $m$ goes from $1$ to $y$.

By the identity of substitution, 
$\displaystyle\int_{t=x}^{t=xy}t^{-1}dt = \displaystyle\int_{t=x}^{t=xy} (xm)^{-1}  \dfrac{dt}{dm} dm $
$ = \displaystyle\int_{t=x}^{t=xy} (xm)^{-1} (x) dm  
= \displaystyle\int_{t=x}^{t=xy} m^{-1} dm
= \displaystyle\int_{m=1}^{m=y} m^{-1} dm
= \ln y
  $